# Magento Custom Module

Tags: magento-1.9

How to install a custom module in magento from admin panel itself, I don't want to copy module files and paste into local folder.

Is there any UI feature for installation a custom module ?

Answer (score 1):

You'll want to use **Magento Connect**. From your Magento Admin Panel (MAP) go to **System** » **Magento Connect** » **Magento Connect Manager**.

Comment: its not working for me i am using magento 1.9.2.I made a module in which i have to add files in app/design/frontend so how can i add those files through module itself

Answer (score 0):

You can do that if you access the magento connect section from System menu item.
You should see an option to upload an archive with your extension.
But in order for this to work, you have to have the archive in a special format compatible with Magento Connect.
If you have a simple archive with all the files and folders it won't work. You will have do to it manually.

Comment: I have tried with .zip,.tar.gz etc its not working Can you tell me what is special format ? I am using magento 1.9.2

Comment: I don't actually know the format. I was never curious about it. In order for it to work , the archive must be built using the magento connect package extension functionality.

Comment: okay,direct through modules can i add files in app/design /frontend which is required in module